# apache camel file component on invocation

Tags: apache-camel

I have a couple of queries regarding the File component in Apache Camel.

From what I have read, file component keeps polling the input folder for a file, and the processing starts once a file is found.

What I am trying to achieve is read a file on invocation from url.

So I designed a producer using jetty. In my process(), I try to read a file form on local disk. This step however dosent get invoked as I think the file component is always listening and its not getting invoked by my request. They are on different threads.

Can anybody please suggest me an alternative or point out if my understanding is wrong somewhere.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to study and learn about enterprise integration patterns
http://camel.apache.org/eip

For example learn about message transformation and content enricher. 
http://camel.apache.org/message-translator.html
http://camel.apache.org/content-enricher.html

Then you can enrich your message with the data from a file.